# Память телефона заполнена

Tags: память

Почему игры и приложения из GooglePlay сохраняются исключительно на внутренней памяти телефона? Она постоянно забита до отказа и не могу ничего скачать, почему нельзя игры и приложения из GooglePlay скачивать на флешкарту?

Comment: Полезный и актуальный вопрос, но к сожалению на этом сайте это оффтопик

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то можно, см. первый же результат по запросу ["игры и приложения из GooglePlay скачивать на флешкарту"](http://allreviews.com.ua/faq/64-ustanovka-prilozheniy-na-kartu-pamyati.html):

1. Откройте меню Вашего устройства и зайдите в "Настройки";
2. Выберите пункт "Приложения";
3. Зайдите в пункт "SD-карта", перед Вами откроется список всех программ, которые поддерживают перенос на карту SD;
4. Если у Вас старая версия ОС Android, нужно зайти в пункт "Управление приложениями" и перейти на закладку "Сторонние";
5. Выберите приложение, которое Вы хотели бы перенести на карту памяти, "тапнув" на нём пальцем;
6. Вы увидите окно приложения, где будет указано, сколько места оно занимает в памяти устройства, кнопки принудительной остановки, деинсталляции и т.д. Нас интересует кнопка "Переместить на карту памяти";
7. Если эта кнопка активна, нажимайте её, и Ваша программа будет перенесена с внутренней памяти устройства на карту SD. Неактивная кнопка свидетельствует о том, что данное приложение функцию переноса на карту памяти не поддерживает.
8. Повторно зайдя в окно приложения после завершения операции, Вы можете наблюдать, что некоторые данные всё равно остались на системном разделе. Это нормально. Главное, что большая часть файлов переместилась на флеш-карту, освободив драгоценное для нас место.

Comment: Этот способ мне знаком! Но не про это вопрос!